# Load images asynchronously in Android ListView in wrong order

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-imageview

I'm running on a problem and I'm unable to solve this issue. I'm accessing Facebook API to retrieve my app users, then I parse the response into a custom object. Everything works fine until there, so I use this information to fill an adapter and set it to a listview. This works great too, but when I try to retrieve the user Facebook profile photo (making a HTTP request), and set it in the associated ImageView control, looks like the class loses the reference to the ImageView and randomly set the photos on listview items.

Does this happened to anyone? Am I clear enough?

Here is the code:

```
public class FacebookFriend {
    public String uid;
    public String name;
}


public class ChooseFriends extends Fragment {

    View vw_layout;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        vw_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choosefriend, container, false);

        ListView lst = (ListView) vw_layout.findViewById(R.id.lstFriends);
        new SearchFacebookFriends(getActivity(), lst).execute("");

    return vw_layout;
    }
}

public class FacebookFriendsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FacebookFriend> {

    public FacebookFriendsAdapter (Context context, int resource, List<FacebookFriend> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgFacebookFriend;
        TextView txtFacebookFriendName;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        FacebookFriend friend = getItem(position);

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_facebook_friend, parent, false);

            viewHolder.imgFacebookFriend = Utils.getImageView(convertView, R.id.imgFacebookFriend);
            viewHolder.txtFacebookFriendName = Utils.getTextView(convertView, R.id.txtFacebookFriendName);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //THIS MEANT TO BE WORKING, FOR EVERY SINGLE ROW, I'M CREATING A NEW INSTANCE PASSING THE CORRECT FACEBOOK UID
        new GetFacebookPhotoAsync(viewHolder.imgFacebookFriend, this).execute(friend.uid);

        //WHEN SET THE NAME WITHOUT AN ASYNC TASK, SHOWS THE CORRECT NAMES
        viewHolder.txtFacebookFriendName.setText(friend.name);

        return convertView;
    }
}

public class SearchFacebookFriends extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private WeakReference<Activity> _activity;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private ListView listView;

    private Activity activity() {
        return _activity.get();
    }

    public SearchFacebookFriends(Activity activity, ListView listView) {
        this._activity = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
        this.listView = listView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity(), "Wait", "...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        //access facebook api and reads app users in json format
        return facebookFriends;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        FacebookFriend[] friends = parseFacebookJsonResponse();

        FacebookFriendsAdapter adapter = new FacebookFriendsAdapter(activity(), 0, Arrays.asList(friends));

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

public class GetFacebookPhotoAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private final WeakReference<ImageView> img;
    private BaseAdapter adapter;

    public BuscaFotoFacebook(ImageView img, BaseAdapter adapter) {
        this.img = new WeakReference<ImageView>(img);
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        //here I make a http request and convert it to a bitmap, works fine
        return Utils.getBitmapFromUrl(String.format("https://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?width=300&height=300", arg0[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        //Looks like the reference is lost here
        ImageView _img = img.get();

        if (_img != null) {
            _img.setImageBitmap(result);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

See some screenshots of what's happening

[image: Repeated photos]

[image: Repeated photos]